# Is there any way to not freeze up the UI when accessing the frequency data of an audio file

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

The following piece of code hangs up the UI when I try to refresh my page after uploading a file. Is it possibly because it's reading the file into memory that's causing the page freeze when I try to refresh? Is there anyway to avoid that if that's the case?

```
document.querySelector("input").oninput = e => {

    let file = e.target.files[0];
    
    file.arrayBuffer().then(arrayBuffer => {

        let ctx = new AudioContext();

        ctx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, audioBuffer => {

            let offlineAudioCtx = new OfflineAudioContext(audioBuffer.numberOfChannels, audioBuffer.length, audioBuffer.sampleRate);

            let bufferSource = offlineAudioCtx.createBufferSource();
            bufferSource.buffer = audioBuffer;

            let analyser = offlineAudioCtx.createAnalyser();
            analyser.fftSize = 2048;
            analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.9;
            let scp = offlineAudioCtx.createScriptProcessor(1024, 0, 1);

            bufferSource.connect(analyser);
            scp.connect(offlineAudioCtx.destination);

            let frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

            scp.onaudioprocess = () => {
                analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);
                // do stuff with frequencyData
            };

            offlineAudioCtx.oncomplete = () => {
                console.log("done");
            };

            bufferSource.start(0);
            offlineAudioCtx.startRendering();

        });

    });
    
}
```

```
<input type="file">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried putting it on a worker? Javascript is single threaded, unless you make use of workers.

Comment: file.arraybuffer() returns a Promise so the works it's doing is async.  I uploaded 30MB, 120MB, and 200+MB files will no impact to the UI.   Maybe there are other areas in your app you need to look for cause?

Comment: Where is the application hosted?  What platform/environment are you testing on?

Comment: @RexHenderson did you run my MWE exactly and see there was no impact on the UI? Or just the part where the file is being converted into an array buffer? Because if I comment out the line `analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);` I don't seem to have the problem anymore. And I'm **sure** there are no other places in my app that are causing the issue. I'm just running this locally.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API

Obsolete: script processor nodes
Before audio worklets were defined, the Web Audio API used the ScriptProcessorNode  for JavaScript-based audio processing. Because the code runs in the main thread, they have bad performance.

Comment: There is a new AudioWorklet that runs on an audio thread instead of the main thread

Comment: @RexHenderson Oh wow really? Dang, I had no idea! Would you, by chance, have a link to an example of an implementation similar to mine using an AudioWorklet?

Comment: Heh. This question had me engrossed. I've been playing around with this all day learning about the Web Audio API.  The OfflineAudioContext is made to process audio quickly, but it is a beast on the CPU. I watch my CPU go from 1% to 14% utilization while the OFC is working.  From all the articles I've read, it's meant for small quick sound bytes, not entire audio tracks.  Here's probably the best OVERALL article on the topic https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/12/audio-worklet   and this one is cited often https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/

Comment: simply put audio processing is resource intensive, and implementers of Web Audio Api are still making inroads into it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's freezing because you use an `OfflineAudioContext` to get the frequency data.  This will run faster (and potentially much faster) than realtime, and you set up your script processor for callbacks every 1024 frames.  With an `AudioContext`, you get callbacks every 20ms or so.  With an OfflineContext, it could be much much faster, so the main thread is spending most of it's time processing the callbacks.